# Soap server using .net core

Tags: .net-core, soap

I have to build a soap service using .Net Core and I am a bit lost.
I saw that there is an extension called SoapCore but the problem for me is to create models

Here is for example the first request I need to manage and the response I have to send

Request:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:ns1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"
 xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
 <SOAP-ENV:Header> 
   <ns2:Security> 
     <ns2:UsernameToken> 
       <ns2:Username>username</ns2:Username> 
       <ns2:Password xsi:type="ns2:http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss- 
       username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</ns2:Password> 
      </ns2:UsernameToken> 
    </ns2:Security> 
 </SOAP-ENV:Header> 
 <SOAP-ENV:Body> 
   <ns1:PingRq EchoToken="e175b2929027fb8bc261948" TimeStamp="2021-11- 
    25T08:05:40+00:00" Version="1.006"> 
      <ns1:EchoData>My Ping message.</ns1:EchoData> 
   </ns1:PingRq> 
  </SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and the response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-
  wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns2="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"> 
    <SOAP-ENV:Header> 
       <ns1:Security>true</ns1:Security> 
    </SOAP-ENV:Header> 
    <SOAP-ENV:Body> 
       <ns2:PingRS EchoToken="PHOBS89d7ec6d6e175b2929027fb8bc261948" TimeStamp="2021-11- 
        25T08:05:33+00:00"> 
           <ns2:Success/> 
           <ns2:EchoData>My Ping message.</ns2:EchoData> 
       </ns2:PingRS> 
    </SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How to manage Soap headers?
How to manage PingRQ tag attributes (EchoToken, Timestamp, Version)

Any help would be appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

To manage headers you'll need to create a custom `IServiceOperationTuner`. This might help: [SoapCore Asp.net core 3.1 Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66432054/soapcore-asp-net-core-3-1-header)